# request.user returns AnonymousUser in a project with react, django and rest framework

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios, django-views

I have a web project what back-end is coded with `django` and front-end is coded with `react`.

In my project, i want to create an order to a special user so this part of project needs to know the user but when i used `request.user` it returned `AnonymousUser`.

here are the `react`, `axios` code and views.py with `rest_framework`:

**react code**

```
    // Hook to save game id and price
    const [all, setAll] = useState({'game': 0, 'price': 0});
    
    // get state
    const location = useLocation();
    const state = location.state;
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setAll({'game': state[0]}, 'price': suggestion);
    }, [])
    
        // To check user confirm suggestion and make order api.
    const orderApi = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            // console.log({'state': state[0], 'suggestion': suggestion});
            console.log(all);
            const {status} = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-1/order/create/', all);
            if (status === 201) {
                console.log('created');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from . import serializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from . import models
from game.models import Game

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def orderCreate(request):
    
    # Here my program return AnonymousUser
    print(str(request.user) + '\n')
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
            .......
            
    orders = models.Order.objects.all()
    serialized = serializer.OrderSerializer(orders, many=True)

    return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

- To write a clean code i didn't write the front-end code and post method codes in my question.
- Please help to retrieve the user object and create order.

Comment: it should be: `orders = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

Comment: `Bamagujen_Bahaushe` problem is not finding user's order. Unfortunately the request.user just return an AnonynousUser object and django can't identify the user when front-end is coded with react.

Comment: Why do you want to use `request.user` on `orderCreate` view?

Comment: `Bamagujen_Bahaushe` Because Order model has a `ForeignKey` to the project customized `User` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days researching on my question, at the end i solved it.

We can use 2 ways to authenticate our users in django.

1. **JWT (Json Web Token)-based authentication**.
2. **session-based authentication**.

I solved my question with the **session-based authentication** way.

Now you can see here the absolute code of **session-based authentication** in a simple **django** and **react** web project step by step:

1. Start the project and app then install **DRF** and **corsheaders** packeages in your terminal:

```
django-admin startproject authentication
python manage.py startapp api
pip install djangorestframework
pip install django-cors-headers
```

2. Add the `rest_framework`, `corsheaders` and **api** app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
]
```

3. Allow any host to send `request` to your django server:

   a) add '*' to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable.

   ```
   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
   ```

   b) add the `corsheaders` variables.

   ```
   CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
   CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
   ```

   c) add the **rest_framework** `authentication` and `permissions` configurations:

   ```
   REST_FRAMEWORK = {
       'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',],
       'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',],}
   ```
4. In your urls.py in the **authentication** directory add a new pattern to the urlpatterns list:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', include('api.a-urls')),
]
```

5. Create a new python file (a-urls.py) in your **api** directory and define a `urlpatterns` list to your **api** app:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from . import views

urlpatterns  =[
    path('register/', views.RegisterView.as_view()),
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view()),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view()),
    path('user/', views.UserView.as_view())
]
```

6. Create `serializers.py` file in the **api** directory and define the serializer classes to `register`, `login` and `identify user`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, authenticate
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

UserModel = get_user_model()

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = '__all__'

        def create(self, clean_data):
            user_obj = self.model.objects.create_user(email=clean_data['email'],
                                                      password=clean_data['password'])
            user_obj.username = clean_data['username']
            user_obj.save()
            return user_obj


class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def check_user(self, clean_data):

        user = User.objects.filter(username=clean_data['username'],
                                   email=clean_data['email']).first()

        if not user:
            raise ValidationError('User not found')
        elif not user.check_password(clean_data['password']):
            raise ValidationError('Password incorrect')
        return user


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('username', 'email')
```

7. In the `views.py` file define the `register`, `login` and `logout` classes:

```
from rest_framework import status, permissions
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . import serializers
from . import validations
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


class RegisterView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        # Here we can validate entire data
        clean_data = validations.UserValidation(request.data).registerValidation()
        serialized = serializers.RegisterSerializer(data=clean_data)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            user = serialized.create(clean_data)
            if user:
                return Response(data=serialized.data,
                                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class LoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        clean_data = validations.UserValidation(data).loginValidation()
        serialized = serializers.LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serialized.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = User.objects.filter(username=clean_data['username'], email=clean_data['email']).first()
            user.check_password(clean_data['password'])
            print(user)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
            return Response(serialized.data,
                            status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)


class LogoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class UserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    # authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)

    def get(self, request):
        print(request.user)
        serialized = serializers.UserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response({'user': serialized.data},
                        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

8. Also we can validate data in another file with a custome validation class so create a `validations.py` file:

```
class UserValidation:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def registerValidation(self):
        ...
        return self.data

    def loginValidation(self):
        ...
        return self.data
```

9. Now, you should test your app with the default **DRF** ui to `post` and `get` data in your browser. First go to the `http:127.0.0.1:8000/register/` and post a user data. If in `inspect> application tab> cookies` you can see the `csrftoken` after registeration like this:[image]

register is ok, and then test the login with default view of **DRF**. After posting the user data it should save `sessionid` in `cookies` like this:[image]

10. If everything in default view of **DRF** is ok, create a new react app and go to its directory to start your react app:

```
npx create-react-app frontend
cd frontend
npm start
```

11. **Don't forget** to add these codes at the top of your user `register`, `login` and `logout` components:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

12. After coding your react app components, you should use the `npm run build` command to get an output directory called build in your frontend directory and add some configurations code to the `settings.py` in backend:

```
# Add a new direction to your templates directions
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates',

            # This is new dir:
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build'),
        ]
        ....


# Add the static files configuration.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/static'),
]
```

13. After changing the `settings.py` file, you should add a new pattern to your `urlpatterns` in `a-urls.py` file like this:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns  =[
    .....
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

Now a base code of backend is ready so if you open `127.0.0.1:8000` in your browser you will see the frontend view with react and an authentication with django.

At the end of my description i want to write a very simple react component to try django authenticatin:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {useState} from 'react';

axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const Try = () => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({'username': 'amiram', 'email': 'example@gmail.com', 'password': 'picodegit'});

    const registerApi = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const status = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/', user).then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            });
            if (status.status === 201) {
                console.log('created');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    const loginApi = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const status = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/', user);
            if (status.status === 202) {
                console.log('accepted');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    const logoutApi = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const status = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/');
            if (status.status === 200) {
                console.log('logged out');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    const check = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const status = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/').then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            if (status.status === 201) {
                console.log('got data');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>hello</div>
            <button onClick={registerApi}>register</button>
            <button onClick={loginApi}>login</button>
            <button onClick={logoutApi}>logout</button>
            <button onClick={check}>check</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default Try;
```

Answer (score 1):

REST API's are stateless, not in a user session.
So there's no user logged on, and Django returns you the Anonymous user.
You will have to pass the user in the post parameters

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess we have 2 ways: 1. Token-based and 2. session-based. But do you know a clear guide to learn about them. Also another question: is `passing the user in the post parameter` safe??

Comment: Session-based approach is not suitable in this case. 
You mention a "special user"... if this special user is a fixed User, you can simply pass a boolean flag in the request to activate this user.

Answer (score 0):

As @stefano mentioned, REST is stateless. By default request.user will be *AnonymousUser* because Django isn't implicitly aware of the user making the request.
If this special user is constant you can probably create a small helper function to return it.

```
def get_special_user():
    special_user_id = 1
    return User.objects.get(id=special_user_id)
```

Then call this function in your view. Otherwise, you will have to set up authentication. I recommend [django rest auth](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)